# Propose to remove [org]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I propose to delete [org](/questions/tagged/org) from Stack Overflow. It has only 4 questions, no wiki summary, and [the "org-preview-latex-fragment" command in emacs org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163217/the-org-preview-latex-fragment-command-in-emacs-org-mode) wrongly used it; it should have used [org-mode](/questions/tagged/org-mode) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited/retagged the four questions. [org](/questions/tagged/org) is no longer linked to any question. It will die after a while if it is not used again.